# Product SKU and inventory on CMS page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, cms

I have a CMS page and would like to add current pricing and display available quantity available called from the product SKU. There is a product ID for each product. The code below is from the category page.   What is the code to display the following:

**Product price**

```
<?php 
if($prd_price == 1){
echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true); 
} 
?>
```

**Qty available inventory**

```
<?php echo($_product->getSku()); ?></td> Available Units: <?php echo $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct ($_product); echo round($stock->getQty()); ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom Magento widget loading information from product and showing them using a template.

Have a look on how to build a custom widget from this link: http://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-widget-magento/

You should simply load the product information from the product id and display them.

Comment: Thank you @RiccardoT What is the code to load the product price and inventory information?

Comment: Simply use the following code to get both ot them:

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$stockQty= Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
$price = $product->getFinalPrice();

Comment: If you wish to load from product SKU instead of product ID replace the load line with:

Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productSku, 'sku');

Comment: Thank you @RiccardoT. I followed the widget instructions and having trouble loading the code block/filename.php. What is the code example? I don't see anything on the frontend webpage.